# How do I subtract two datetime values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-arithmetic, sqldatetime

I have a table with two columns `login` and `logout`.  If a row has values "2019-08-07 20:37:12" in `login` column and "2019-08-07 21:14:16" in `logout` column, I want the difference between time values from login and logout columns.

I have:

```
SELECT logintime,CONVERT(varchar(6),DATEDIFF(second, login, logout)/3600)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),(DATEDIFF(second, login,logout) % 3600) / 60), 2)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(second, login, logout) % 60), 2) 
AS 'HH:MM:SS' from face_login_logout
```

Expected result is `'2019-08-07 01:23:04 '`.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the usage of `convert()` and `datediff()` and `+` as the string concatenation operator

Comment: And what if login and logout would be in different day, f.e.:
login "2019-08-07 23:37:12"
logout "2019-08-08 00:14:16"

What date is expected?

Comment: What's your actual result, and why did you expect a date in the answer?

Comment: When you subtract a date with another date, the result will be the difference in no. of days/hours/mins/secs NOT like the way you have mentioned in the expected result.

Comment: iam using postgress

Comment: i want to know the difference on that particular date and in values date also included thats why im expecting date

Comment: i did not receive anysolution please help me in finding the solution

Comment: But what shoudl be your result? The difference between those two dates in your example is 00:37:04. How did you get '2019-08-07 01:23:04' in your answer? I dont get it

Comment: *"iam using postgress"* Are you *sure*? I thought PostgreSQL used `||` for string concatenation (It does according to it's [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html)).

Answer (score 0):

As @lypskee has suggested, I think your calculations are out.

I found the method below (which looks to be the same as your code) and it tells me that there is a difference of `0:37:04`

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME
DECLARE @END_DATE   DATETIME
SET     @START_DATE = '2019-08-07 20:37:12'
SET     @END_DATE =   '2019-08-07 21:14:16'

SELECT    CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEDIFF(second, @START_DATE, @END_DATE)/3600)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEDIFF(second, @START_DATE, @END_DATE) % 3600) / 60), 2)
+ ':'
+ RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(second, @START_DATE, @END_DATE) % 60), 2) AS 'HH:MM:SS'
```

## update - adjusted for pulling from a table.

```
SELECT login, logout, CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEDIFF(second, login, logout)/3600)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), (DATEDIFF(second, login, logout) % 3600) / 60), 2)
    + ':'
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2), DATEDIFF(second, login, logout) % 60), 2) AS 'difference'

FROM tbl_name
```

This would give you the result for each row in your table...you can adjust the query for any null values too.

Output:

```
login                |  logout               |  difference
-----------------------------------------------------------
2019-08-07 20:37:12  |  2019-08-07 21:14:16  |  0:37:04
```

Comment: but in this method we are providing values for start date,end date what if for more then one row we cant provide values every time no

Comment: so you want to run this over a table? I've added an edit above

Comment: it showing  the ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: SELECT logintime, logout, CONVERT(varchar(6), DATEDIFF(secon...

Comment: can you post your full SQL. The above works for me so it could be something in the syntax of your own query

Comment: then wt about if we use sql query in postgress i.e.,pg admin3

Comment: @nikithachevva I suggest you close and start a new or edit this question with the right tags as you've specified the wrong database in your post

Comment: i got the result by using the query SELECT (loginout::timestamp - logintime::timestamp) from face_login_logout. but i want the loginout,logintime columns also with the resultant query and should display the new column with column name 'difference'

Comment: Sorry, it's really difficult to follow what you're implementing from comments. You should update your OP with more detail if you need further help. The above query I posted works based on the information I have(/had) but if you need different SQL syntax based on another database or you have more info - post it above

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for your example:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-08-07 21:14:16','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-08-07 20:37:12','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

But it gives 00:37:04 as a result.

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(logout,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - TO_TIMESTAMP(login,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @logintime DATETIME='2019-08-07 20:37:12'
DECLARE @logouttime DATETIME='2019-08-07 21:14:16'

SELECT CAST(CAST(@logouttime AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(20))+' '+
   CAST(ABS(DATEPART(HOUR,@logouttime)-DATEPART(HOUR,@logintime)) AS VARCHAR(20))+':'+
   CAST(ABS(DATEPART(MINUTE,@logouttime)-DATEPART(MINUTE,@logintime)) AS VARCHAR(20))+':'+
   CAST(ABS(DATEPART(SECOND,@logouttime)-DATEPART(SECOND,@logintime)) AS VARCHAR(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, if you're sure that the difference is less than 24 hours, you can use [`timefromparts`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/timefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get the difference as a `time` data type. I've also used cross apply to only write the `datediff` once instead of three times.

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE face_login_logout
(
    login datetime,
    logout datetime
)

INSERT INTO face_login_logout (login, logout) VALUES
('2019-08-07T20:37:12','2019-08-07T21:14:16')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  login, 
        logout, 
        TIMEFROMPARTS(
            Difference / 3600, 
            (Difference % 3600) / 60, 
            Difference % 60, 
            0,
            0 
        ) As TimeDiff
FROM face_login_logout
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, login, logout) As Difference) c
```

Results:

```
login                   logout                  TimeDiff
2019-08-07 20:37:12     2019-08-07 21:14:16     00:37:04
```

If you want a `datetime` as result, simply use `datetimefromparts`

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to subtract (or add) two `datetime` values in SQL Server is:

```
DECLARE @login  datetime = '2019-08-07 20:37:12';
DECLARE @logout datetime = '2019-08-07 21:14:16';

SELECT @logout - @login AS ElapsedTime;
```

```
ElapsedTime
-----------------------
1900-01-01 00:37:04.000

(1 row affected)
```